# 'filters' is not a registered tag library

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I have an issue regarding template filter. I have used **django allauth** for user registration. I have edited its signup.html and used loop to iterate over the fields to show them dynamically. I could show the fields but could not define the type field.

What i did is

**account/signup.html**

```
{% load filters %}
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in forms.visible_fields %}
        <input type="{{ field.field.widget|input_type}}" name="{{ field.name }}" id="{{ field.id_for_label}}" class="form-control">
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**template filter inside main app(filters.py)**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter('input_type')
def input_type(ob):
    return ob.__class__.__name__
```

**templates location**

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

As i am using django allauth where should i place my template filter code? Sign up form to extend the allauth form using first name and last name is inside main app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag library should be placed in a `templatetags` directory in the root directory of the app:

See code layout from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout):

> When a Django app is added to `INSTALLED_APPS`, any tags it defines in
>   the conventional location described below are automatically made
>   available to load within templates.
>
> The app should contain a `templatetags` directory, at the same level as
>   `models.py`, `views.py`, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it -
>   don’t forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated
>   as a Python package.

Comment: Yes, i did that way but i was not sure where should i place my templatetags directory. Because i am using allauth package for user signup. But my sign up form is in main app means that i have to put it inside main app. Am i right? I will give this a try.

Comment: The location of the `templatetags` directory is irrespective of that of the signup form

Comment: I am still getting same error. I created a folder called templatetags and inside that i created two file one __init__.py and another filters.py with above code. I then loaded the filters in account/signup.html using {% load filters %} as filters.py is the name and then inside type field i did {{ field.field.widget|input_type}}" but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: my project structure is myproject > main_app, myproject, templates(here django allauth template resides as account/signup.html). I placed templatetags inside main_app.

Comment: Is `main_app` an *app*? And is it included in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes its an app. Also it is included inside INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Do i have to define templatetags inside allauth package? Also my template is not inside app. It is outside. All app share that same template directory.

Comment: Now the problem is solved. I am getting field type as TextInput and PasswordInput but PasswordInput is displaying the password in clear text instead of dot. Why is that so? How can i overcome this?

Comment: @milan I think it is better if you ask that as a new question

Comment: I have posted a new question. Can you please look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575910/password-field-is-showing-password-in-plain-text

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the error for me. I added this to the **init**.py

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```