# password field is showing password in plain text

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I have used django allauth for user registration and login system. I could show the form by simplifying the lines of code using for loop. I got the right field type(TextInput and PasswordInput) for each field too. However the password field which has PasswordInput shows password in plain text. How can i resolve this?

**my signup page(account/signup.html)**

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
     {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
        {{ field.errors.0 }}
        <input type="{{field|input_type}}" name="{{ field.name }}" class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label}}">
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**filters.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter('input_type')
def input_type(field):
    print('field',field.field.widget.__class__)
    return field.field.widget.__class__.__name__
```

How can i show password in dot?

Comment: can you show what does the print say ?

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński field <class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'>
field <class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'>
field <class 'django.forms.widgets.TextInput'>
field <class 'django.forms.widgets.PasswordInput'>
field <class 'django.forms.widgets.PasswordInput'>

Comment: Why don't you just use `{{ field }}`?

Comment: Why do you do this `<input type="{{field|input_type}}" name="{{ field.name }}" class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label}}">`? If you do this only for adding `class` to field, you can add it in form class in `__init__` method or user https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks/

Comment: yes i can but the problem is how can i pass class="form-control" in input element?

Comment: So this is why you have problems. Your template will not render your input as a password, because HTML does not understand `django.forms.widgets.PasswordInput` - you need to set type="password" and it will work just fine

Comment: I'm not sure what led you to create that filter, or why you thought the class name would be the appropriate thing to use in the type attribute. Can you explain?

Comment: You can add class in this way: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].widget['class'] = 'form-control'` if your form class

Comment: You could use this instead: [Looping over the form’s fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

Comment: I did not knew that HTML does not understand PasswordInput. Sorry for my ignorance. The only thing that i used that way is to use class=form-control in all input element of signup.html.

Comment: I have used django-allauth. So where should i override __init__ ?

Comment: You should override form, see the allauth documentation here http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_FORMS (={}) - Used to override forms, for example: {‘login’: ‘myapp.forms.LoginForm’}
But better use django-widget-tweaks

Comment: 'PasswordInput' object does not support item assignment. I get this error when overriding init function.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, it should looks like this `self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'`

Comment: Its working now.         {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
         {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field.errors }}
                     {{field}}
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}

Comment: @AnnaVracheva Can you post this in answer? I will mark it as answered.

Comment: I want to know one more thing. Why django-widget-tweaks is best than overriding init function?

Comment: In my opinion it is better adding html classes, placeholders and other data attributes in html. This make easier to read your code and often you need to add not only class but other attributes. And the second idea is if you work with  frontend developer, they can add attributes by himself. And you can see django-crispy-forms as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add class by overriding `__init__` method in form class

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
    self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Answer (score 1):

The password is showing in plain text because you're assigning `<input>` types incorrectly, therefore not hiding passwords as `<input type="password">` does.

From reading the comments, it looks like you're trying to add custom bootstrap classes to the form fields. As [Anna Vracheva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6663134/anna-vracheva) was saying, you can add the class to the fields using the form's `__init__` method.

```
from django import forms

class CustomForm("""Whichever class you're inheriting from, probably ModelForm"""):
    # If you're using AllAuth, this is already defined on the form
    password = fields.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput) 
    # Or whatever field, for that matter

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomFieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Option 1 - Assign to only password
        self.fields['password'].widget['class'] = 'form-control'

        # Option 2 - Loop over all fields and assign to all
        for field in self.fields:
            field.widget['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Then, instead of manually rendering HTML, let Django's Templates do that:

```html
<!-- This -->
{{ field }}
<-- -->
<!-- Instead of this -->
<input type="{{field|input_type}}" name="{{ field.name }}" 
       class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label}}">
```

That should fix any field rendering problems you're having while preserving your form classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}"
                   name="{{ field.name }}"
                   id="id_{{ field.name }}" >
```